# Cannot Boot Ubuntu from DVD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I have an older Gateway desktop computer that I installed a version of Ubuntu in 2010.  For reasons I won't go into here I decided to uninstall it, which left the file structure on the disk--disks, docs, install, winboot and Uninstall-Ubuntu.  The dual boot prompt remained also.  Now, I would like to reinstall Ubuntu 14.10 but I cannot boot from the DVD (an Ubuntu DVD, not one I created).

What I get is a purple splash screen, no other text and then it goes to a black screen and text begins scrolling.  This appears to be a script running that is identifying the hardware I have on this system. This hangs at an IR device and that is as far as I goes.  I don't have an IR device installed but I have used an IR device that plug into the USB port.

This has been a problem for some time since I have tried to boot various versions of Ubuntu on this system with the same results.

I'm thinking that the previous version of Ubuntu (10??) that I had installed and then having gone through the uninstall process created this condition.  Re-running the uninstall does not remove the Ubuntu folder structure from the disk nor does it fix the problem.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: take out whatever unnecessary hardware from your USB port. Also maintain one display only during installation.

Comment: Please don't use 14.10: it's End-Of-Life...

Answer (score 0):

Install fresh copy of [Ubuntu 14.04lts](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on a USB flash drive, boot into "try Ubuntu mode" Run install, select repair current Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try it from pen drive  :D
The general procedure to install Ubuntu (or Ubuntu flavour, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) from a USB flash drive is:

Acquire the correct Ubuntu installation files ('the ISO')
Put Ubuntu onto your USB flash drive
Configure your computer to boot from USB flash drive and boot from it
Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it

Install Ubuntu to your internal drive (hard disk drive or solid state drive).